# Docker Port forward command from linux VM -> windows VM

Tags: python, linux, bash, docker, visual-studio-code

I am working on one dockerization script to host react application.
I have ensured installing necessary and am able to host the application in Linux VM.

But I couldn't reach it from Azure VM even though i used port forwarding while running the container.
container running

```html
docker run -p 80:80 react_image
```

```
Azure VM -> Linux VM -> Container Image
```

If i am connecting from localhost:80 in Azure VM, Not redirecting application

But if use Port forwarding in VScode its allowing me to connect application.
[image]
Is there any command i can use to repliate VSCode port forwarding ?

Please suggest me the your views, i am out of options.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_forwarding-a-port-creating-ssh-tunnel Can this help?

Comment: Thanks for response @MingJie-MSFT actually i am searching linux command to replicate same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using reverse proxy (for e.g. NGINX)

Comment: Hi,  If possible would you elaborate or add me some links.